# regex validator with RadMaskedTextBox zip code with mask #####-#### 5 or 9 (C#, asp.net)

Tags: regex, validation, zip, zipcode, radmaskedtextbox

How do you use a RadMaskedTextBox field for zip code with a #####-#### mask and an asp RegEx validator?  The Regex is acting funny and not working as it should...?

I want these valid entries only:

55555

55555-5555

Comment: You may separate the answer from the question and post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the issue....the validator is trying to validate the literal character and the prompt characters.

This is how to use a asp regex validator with a telerik RadMaskedTextBox that has a mask of #####-#### and be able to accept 5 numbers or 9 numbers.

the regex expression that worked for me is: ^\d{5}-?(?:_{4})?(?:[-\s]?\d{4})?$

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valRegexZip" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must be valid!" ControlToValidate="txtZip" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^\d{5}-?(?:_{4})?(?:[-\s]?\d{4})?$"  ValidationGroup="valGroupStep1" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I had issues with the mask because the the validator was trying to validate "55555-____" literally with the dash and the underscores. This validator takes that into consideration (the data is only passed in as "55555")

Also, you may can use other regex expressions by turning off the prompt char property of the masked text box.

Hope this helps save someones time!